# Type U (generic) is not assignable to type unknown

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a generic Repository class and each Repository has its own Sub-Repositories.
The Sub-Repositories and kept by a Record {String: Repository}.
It looks like this:

```
export class Repository<T> {
  private readonly collection: Record<string, T> = {};
  private readonly subrepositories: Record<string, Repository<unknown>> = {};
.
.
  subrepository<U>(docName: string) {
    if (!this.subrepositories[docName]) {
      this.subrepositories[docName] = new Repository<U>();
    }
    return this.subrepositories[docName];
  }
```

In this line: `this.subrepositories[docName] = new Repository<U>();` I get typescript error:

```
TS2322: Type 'Repository<U>' is not assignable to type 'Repository<unknown>'.
Types of property 'set' are incompatible.
Type '(id: string, data: U) => void' is not assignable to type '(id: string, data: unknown) => void'.
Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'U'.
'U' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'unknown'.
```

The only way I managed to overcome the issue is by casting `this.subrepositories` first to `unknown` and then to `Record<string, Repository<U>` like that:

```
  subrepository<U>(docName: string) {
    if (!this.subrepositories[docName]) {
      (this.subrepositories as unknown as Record<string, Repository<U>>)[
        docName
      ] = new Repository<U>();
    }
    return this.subrepositories[docName];
  }
```

But is it really a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type is probably invariant on the type parameter `T`. This happens if you use a type parameter in both a covariant position (such as a field) and a contravariant position (such a as a function parameter). You can learn more about variance [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EInunOVRsUU)

```
export class Repository<T> {
  private readonly collection: Record<string, T> = {};
  private readonly subrepositories: Record<string, Repository<unknown>> = {};
  fn!: (p: T) => void; // Remove this and asssignability works
  subrepository<U>(docName: string) {
    if (!this.subrepositories[docName]) {
      this.subrepositories[docName] = new Repository<U>();
    }
    return this.subrepositories[docName];
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4CViTQSxmgE8AeAFQD44BvAKDjjCnwDcUZg4pgUATCADskxRBCRJgCGPiEAubFOh9SaGC0EBzADRwqcALy0AvgG4GTFu07deA4aLQBXAEY88haPmBoFOBMqq6vhaujgeRFBkToIA1oIQAO6ClNRGNGYWAGaCAIQKABRgCuQAlIbUrBD4fKZwAPT1igC2EKxcMAAW+Jgognxw6Bj4moIoLvhIhKKJ0LFoFs5uuBAEkWQAqpQFAggAcijNwApqGprl9IyM+FlwBbldPQB0S+6rniw+ANq7B0cAuhcLFc4I80C9XG81l5vr9DsB-oY4IJgIlFBESKQtgVSuYQcZgbYYE4oIJQd1wa8VtDPmgfhB9vD-ni4ATjEA)

The reason this doesn't work is that it is actually not type safe. Since you could pass in a type that wasn't expected by the function.

```
  sampleMethod() {
      const rep = this.subrepository<{ a: number} >("foo");
      rep.fn =  p => p.a.toFixed();

      
      const repAlias = this.subrepository<{ a: string} >("foo");
      repAlias.fn({ a: "" }) // 
  }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKCmAHA9hAlgF2QJwJ4B4AVAPmgG8AoaaRbNANzA3mm3jABNkA7EXaYMhAh4wDGh4AuOKJwd8EDHW4BzADTQS0ALzkAvgG4qNOo2at2XXvwgBXAEZsU6LHXgRpCQdnmLl6mWdMHAJbbgBrbmQAd25iUl0yQ2MAM24AQmkACkRpQgBKHVJ6ZDQOA2gAekqZAFtkehYMAAs0GDBuDmhIKDQVbjB7NBBMfmiccIhjO0ckVGC8fABVYiyuYAA5MFr4aT80VXzPOZcQ5dJKamo0FOgs9Ja2gDoZp3nXNHcAbXWtnYBdQqXK7UR4QF4ON6nNwQH7ITbbeD-HTQbjwaKBd5nMKRGJxLL5IwgvTGahsDC2bDcaBgiGzIIfb6-RHIyCY6EEFZE6Ak6bbRAiACy8BayA4BPIpKugm4igsiBRtNeJwWBDI3Wk3FstXs8GwemgqwARClkMgjYSpWSkE80iiaEUaE8wE8sAAxNAAD3g4stVug-plcqcAEERmzdErISrXGqNdB9qoDcbTebLSDrYgw2hILbuFl1WBpEajTzCtVoIBeDcApTvGEm8tEYhAMkIEl78oUi5pigkGIA)

Also you should avoid using type parameters in a single position, as they don't provide a lot of type safety, usually just masking type assertions